# Pass AD-User from Client to IIS-Server to DB-Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

Is it somehow possible to pass the AD-User from a client to the `IIS`-Server and then use this AD-User to log on the `SQL-Server`? So what i need looks like this:

```
--client--               ---IIS---              -------SQL-Server-------
|AD-User |  --AD-User--> |WebPage| --AD-User--> |Logged on with AD-User|
----------               ---------              ------------------------
```

This only works if the `SQL-Server` is on the same Server as the `IIS`:

```
--client--               -------Server-------
|AD-User |  --AD-User--> |IIS withWebPage   |
----------               |SQL-Server with DB|
                         --------------------
```

But it works not if `IIS` and `SQL-Server` are on two different machines.

Does anybody know how to pass the AD-User from the client to `IIS` to `SQL-Server` over two different machines? Which settings do i have to make?

Comment: [Understanding Kerberos Double Hop](https://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunatly that does not work using NTLM authentication. The issue is that your user cannot be authenticated to the next hop without knowing your password. This is not known to the IIS server, as only password-based hashes are used to authenticate from client to IIS. You can find more information by searching for 'Double Hop Authentication'.

Here is an article that describes this problem:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx

I had the same issue some time ago and decided to use a service account using SQL authentication for the DB access. Kerberos was not an option because not implemented at the clients infrastucture.

Hope that helps...

Comment: provide more details not link.

Comment: link contains more details :) added small issue description though.